# How I can do property transfer in SOAP UI from one test case to another

Tags: soapui

I want to transfer the session id from the response to another request in other test case but not able to do that.

Below is the response which is one test case :

```
{"CTIResponse": {
   "header":    {
      "transactionId": "2536233651001",
      "businessProcessId": "BPID25362345264",
      "globalId": "str1234",
      "sender": "MWNL",
      "receiver": "TMNL",
      "messageType": "str1234"
   },
   "body":    {
      "status": "SUCCESS",
      "code": "",
      "message": "",
      "session_id": "1047531556880950",
      "activity_id": "2238701802"
   }
}}
```

Below is the request in another test case:

```
{"CTIRequest": {
   "body":    {
      "id": "104753155685201021",
      "input": "PhoneNumber=31699981473",
      "time": "2015-03-16T08:02:15Z",
      "intentions": "Residential",
      "subtype": "ARRIVAL",
      "login": "EXT_CTI",
      "type": "CTI"
   },
   "header":    {
      "timestamp": "str1234",
      "sender": "TMNL",
      "businessProcessId": "BPID452632652KLM",
      "transactionId": "25362685121",
      "receiver": "MWNL",
      "globalId": "str1234",
      "messageType": "str1234"
   }
}}
```

I want that the session ID which is received from the above response to be sent to the field "id" in the request.

Comment: I somehow did that but the session id is received in [] brackets. How I can remove this brackets?

Comment: You need to show your attempts. See [ask] for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! But still I am receiving the [] brackets .I don't want any [] bracket .How I could get this?

Answer (score 2):

In the JSONPath expression of your source property transfer, just add `[0]` to the end of your expression. For example:

```
$..session_id[0]
```

This will exclude the brackets.

Comment: I am using this $..body.session_id[0] in the source property and the result is coming in square bracket like [1236253233],How I can get the result without these square brackets?

Comment: If you're looking at the Property Transfer dialog in the Transferred Values column, you probably will still see the square brackets. If you check where the value has been transferred to, it should be without the brackets. For example, try transferring to a custom property at the test case level rather than directly to the new request. That will show the bracket-less value.

Comment: I checked in the custom property, at the testsuite level, the value is displayed without square brackets but in other test case , at the property level , I mentioned ${#TestSuite#testProperty} and after running this , its showing as INvalid JSON:value

Comment: How are you retrieving the value for `${#TestSuite#testProperty}` once it's been populated with the session ID?